# How to improve the Java Stream method?

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to improve the following Java Stream method and to understand better how does anyMatch in Stream work.

In my example the `get(blogContext.getBlogContextEnum().getTagName(), new String[0])` can have one or many tags. Will the `anymatch` iterate through each value that comes from the previous get?

When `showAllTopics && currentFilterTag.equals("xxx:content/something"`) evaluates to `true` it should check that blogTags contain the resource tag.
When `showAllTopics && currentFilterTag.equals("xxx:content/something"`) evaluates to `false` it should check resource tag matches the currentFilterTag.

I could of course solve it with if statements but would like to learn using `Streams` for that.

The blogTags is a class variable of type `private List<String> blogTags`;

```
private boolean containsSelectedTag(Resource resource) {
        Stream<String> tagStream = Arrays.stream(resource.getValueMap().get(blogContext.getBlogContextEnum().getTagName(), new String[0]));
        boolean containsSelectedTag = showAllTopics && currentFilterTag.equals("xxx:content/something") ?
                tagStream.anyMatch(tag -> blogTags.contains(tag)) : tagStream.anyMatch(tag -> tag.contains(currentFilterTag));
        return containsSelectedTag;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be [a topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since it's not a problem at all nor would somebody else find this helpful since this is a specific question, not a general one. This would most likely fall into the "Seeking reccomendations" flag since this is seeking reccomendations and would most likely lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: It's not clear in which way you want to improve this. What exactly, according to you, is wrong with the existing code?

Comment: Hello there @Anuska, it seems like you didn't understood what I have said. What I meant there was this question is "Seeking recommendations", hence I flagged it us such. Because it was flagged, it can be closed or deleted by moderators.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper I would like to understand better how does  anyMatch in Stream work. In my example the `get(blogContext.getBlogContextEnum().getTagName(), new String[0])` can have one or many tags. Will the `anymatch` iterate through each value that comes from the previous get?

Comment: That's very simple: `anyMatch` will check if there is an item in the stream for which the predicate returns `true`. In your code: if there is a tag in the stream of tags that is also present in `blogTags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this be considered as improvement?

```
private boolean containsSelectedTag(Resource resource) {
    Stream<String> tagStream = Arrays.stream(resource.getValueMap().get(blogContext.getBlogContextEnum().getTagName(), new String[0]));
    boolean containsSelectedTag = 
        tagStream.anyMatch(tag -> showAllTopics && currentFilterTag.equals("xxx:content/something") ? blogTags.contains(tag)) : tag.contains(currentFilterTag));
    return containsSelectedTag;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the original approach of *not* repeating the test of `showAllTopics && currentFilterTag.equals("xxx:content/something")` for every stream element was better. However, you still can write a single `anyMatch` call and avoid the repeated test at the same time. `private boolean containsSelectedTag(Resource resource) { return Arrays.stream( resource.getValueMap().get(blogContext.getBlogContextEnum().getTagName(), new String[0])) .anyMatch(showAllTopics && currentFilterTag.equals( "xxx:content/something")? tag -> blogTags.contains(tag): tag -> tag.contains(currentFilterTag)); }`